# Записать данные бинарного дерева в массив

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, бинарное-дерево, запись

Проблема в том, что при записи данных бинарного дерева в массив, записываются не все данные.
Например,дерево содержит вот такие данные:

```
76  Сидоров
60  Петров
54  Артуров
49  Иванов
41  Денисов
3  Волков
```

Но в массив записываются только:

```
49 Иванов
41 Денисов
60 Петров
54 Артуров
76 Сидоров
```

Среда:Builder c++
Сам код:

```
 struct Tree {
 int info;
 String name;
 Tree *left, *right;
 }*root;

 String **array;
 int size = NodeCount(root); /* функция NodeCount подсчитывает количество 
 узлов, для того чтобы знать какой размерности объявлять массив.(Работает 
 корректно)*/
 array = new String*[size];   //объявляю двумерный массив 
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)         
 array[i] = new String[2]; 
 addToArray(root,array,0); // думаю в этой функции проблема....
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
      Memo1->Lines->Add(array[i][0] + ' ' + array[i][1]); // вывод массива
 }
 /* --------Сама функция-----*/
 void addToArray(Tree *root,String **a,int idx)
 {
 a[idx][0] = IntToStr(root->info);
 a[idx][1] = root->name;
 if (root->left)  addToArray(root->left,a,++idx);
 if (root->right) addToArray(root->right,a,++idx);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас перезаписываются значения, т.к. при сохранении значений правого узла дерева, в массиве на этом месте уже может что-то быть. Решить это можно просто передавая вместо int idx, int& idx например. Только не забудьте создать переменную с начальным значение 0 в вызывающем коде.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку.Я безмерно вам благодарен! while(true) cout<<"спасибо";